# How to rename Chinese named files with VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, character, cjk

I have the path of the files stored in MS Access in a table.

The table was made to rename a specific set of files, so the important fields are oldpath and newpath. These are used in VBA. First I bring the the data setting a recordset. Afterwards I do a while not to process all the oldpath using RenameFileOrDir function.

The function renames all file names that are not in Chinese.

```vb
Public Function TestNameStatement() 
    Dim fOK As Boolean

    Set rs_images = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select import_acc.* from import_acc") 
    rs_images.MoveLast 
    rs_images.MoveFirst

    Do While Not rs_images.EOF

        oldlocation = rs_images.Fields("oldpath") 
        newlocation = rs_images.Fields("newpath")

        ' Folders must exist for Source, but do not need to exist for destination 
        fOK = RenameFileOrDir("" & oldlocationx & "", "" & newlocationx & "")

        rs_images.MoveNext
    Loop 
    On Error Resume Next

End Function
```

[image: Access table]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Access options, Language,add chinese language

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note [StackOverflow doesn't work like a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - small sentences like this one - that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)